# JavaScript: Access Parent Object Properties from Child Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have three classes as detailed below. I have the topmost class Workout, which contains instances of the Exercise class which itself contains instances of the Set class.

How can the set object access the properties & methods of the Workout/Exercise objects without passing down a reference of the top-level containing object as we go down along the heirarchy of objects?

```
class Set {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    get name() {
        return this.name;
    }

    listParentObjectProperties() {
        //output Workout object properties
        //output Exercise objet properties
    }
}

class Exercise {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    get name() {
        return this.name;
    }

    get sets() {
        return [
            new Set("Set 1"),
            new Set("Set 2"),
            new Set("Set 3"),
        ]
    }
}

class Workout {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    get name() {
        return this.name;
    }

    get Exercises() {
        return [
            new Exercise("Barbell Squat"),
            new Exercise("Barbell Bench Press")
        ]
    }
}

let sampleWorkout = new Workout("Sample Workout 1");

sampleWorkout.Exercises[0].sets[0].listParentObjectProperties();
```

Comment: I'd consider naming my objects different from build ins

Comment: @chrispbacon Assuming I rename my objects, how to I access the parent objects methods/properties?

Comment: I don't think that's possible without passing a reference

Comment: There is no connection in your setup, a workout doesn't know anything about the exercises, and exercises don't know about the sets, how would you imagine the connections to be?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid passing down a reference? As it is now, a Set could be associated with multiple exercises so there is no way to know just one.

Comment: are you looking for a javascript closure? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures